# Windows 10 two-finger scrolling not smooth on precision touchpad

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

Usually, when one places two fingers upon the touchpad and moves them up or down, the page will smoothly scroll up or down depending on the direction of the fingers/how fast they move. However, if I place two fingers upon my touchpad, and move them up and down, the page will teleport seemingly based upon how far I moved my fingers before lifting them.

This only happens, however, if I place the two fingers upon the touchpad at the same time. If I first place one finger down, and then the second, scrolling works perfectly, but this gesture is rather unnatural. I'm assumed this jerky scrolling was due to conflict with some other command, such as two-finger tap to right click, but after disabling this (and pinch to zoom (which is also not smooth btw)), the issue still persists.

Any way I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue: it had to do with eye tracking technology, specifically Tobii eye tracking. If you go into Tobii eye tracking settings and disable the two-finger touch feature, it fixes the issue.